# LibClamAV Error:cl_load:No such file or directory: C:\Users\my-pc\Desktop\clamav-win32-clamav-0.99\contrib\msvc\Debug\Win32\db

Tags: visual-studio-2010, antivirus, antivirus-integration

I downloaded Clamwin source code and loaded the clamwin solution to visual studio(2010 professional) and successfully built all project without any errors. After clicking `start without debugging`(seting `clamscan` project as startup )  I'am getting bellow error on cmd-prompt.

```
LibClamAV Error:cl_load:No such file or directory: C:\Users\my-pc\Desktop\clamav-win32-clamav-0.99\contrib\msvc\Debug\Win32\db
-----------SCAN SUMMARY-------------
Known viruses: 0
Engine version: 0.97.8
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 0
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 0.003 sec (0 m 0 s)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I searched solution  online and I got  `Clam is looking for it's database files and the directory doesn't have them, doesn't exist, or Clam doesn't have sufficient rights to access the files.` 
But how should I solve this? should I create file or directory in that path or  should I make it find itself?

Answer (score 3):

Just run freshclam -> downloads fresh vc db to predefined dir (DatabaseDirectory in freshclam.conf). Before you do this, you must set up the freshclam.conf.

Then set up the same DatabaseDirectory in clam.conf.
(There was a bug here for me. I was installing on Windows and used forward slashes all over the config files as dir delimiter of path. At DatabaseDirectory value i had to change my forward slashes to backslashes to be able to run clamdscan successfully)

Finally, try run clamscan.

Please, tell me, if it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in question `Clam is looking for it's database files and the directory`, directory /db should be updated with database by Running the freshclam tool,to run freshclam(if there is an Error), download the `freshclam.conf` file and edit the file as required.Then click on `start debugging` from the debug menu. Clamscan scans current working directory. For more information on [clamscan](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clamscan)